# Qt apps break after build on MinGW

Tags: qt, build, mingw, entry-point

When I build Qt 4.8.2 it builds successfuly. But when I run any Qt pre-built apps (qtdemo.exe, designer.exe etc) it throws a procedure entry point error.

This is what it says:

[image]

I just can't get it to work!

I have build debug and release DLLs, without Phonon, Script, Qt3support, or webkit.

---

I opened the app in Dependency Walker and this is what it said in bold red text:

> Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
>
> Error: Modules with
> different CPU types were found.
>
> Warning: At least one delay-load
> dependency module was not found. Warning: At least one module has an
> unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load
> dependent module.

Comment: Are those pre-built Qt apps built using the same version of Qt?

Comment: They were installed by the installer I got from the website.

Comment: What installer? Are you using Qt Creator? If you're not already using Qt Creator, try using it. It would never give you those problems.

Comment: Don't try to mix Qt/mingw and Qt/msvc libraries, that won't work. Make sure the Qt libraries you use at runtime are built with the compiler you compiled your application with.

Comment: I've only built MinGW libaries. I haven't got MSVC libraries.

Comment: "Error: Modules with different CPU types were found" - perhaps the  downloaded executables were built for x86 (32-bit) and the MinGW you're using is targeting x64 (64-bit)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs when there is another version of the QtCore4.dll in you system PATH. You can get around this by copying the newly compiled dll's into the same directory as the executable, so that it finds the correct version.

You could search your system for QtCore4.dll to see which program(s) installed the conflicting files.